# Resolving dependencies in Rust 32 bit cross-compilation

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, nanomsg

I'm working on a project that uses the [nanomsg](https://crates.io/crates/nanomsg) crate. The crate depends on the nanomsg library itself, which is a native library. So far so good.

The problem comes when I cross compile the project to target the raspberry pi using the following command:

```
cargo build --target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

The build fails when trying to link the nanomsg library with the following error:

```
error: linking with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-5` failed: exit code: 1
...
  = note: /usr/local/lib/libnanomsg.so: file not recognized: File format not recognised
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have configured my machine for such cross-compilation beforehand and confirmed it works with a simple hello world project.

Some searching for the error message points to 64bit vs 32bit issues with the library. The nanomsg library I have installed is 64bit, built from source.

Is there a way to tell cargo to statically link that library and resolve it at runtime? If I install a 32bit version of the library on my machine, will cargo simply "pick it up" and cross-compilation will succeed?

Comment: I don't think things are working as you intended. `/usr/local/lib/libnanomsg.so` would be a *very* strange place to install a cross-compiled native library. You need to find the location of your statically-linked cross-compiled version of nanomsg and link to that.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain myself correctly. /usr/local/lib/libnanomsg.so is not the cross compiled version of the library, is the 64bit version of the library that works in my host machine (64bit Ubuntu). It seems reasonable that if cargo is picking it up for cross compilation, it would fail. That's one of my questions, how do I tell cargo to pick up a different version of the library?

Comment: Or the more general: How do I cross compile a project that includes nanomsg from Ubuntu 64bit to Raspbian 32bit?

Comment: Have you already read about [build scripts](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html)?

Comment: I had not, I'll check it out, thanks.